# Display failure spreaded to half of monitor

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, defective-hardware

I plugged my external 4K monitor (actual resolution 1920x1080 @ 60Hz) via DisplayPort to my laptop to extend the screen. This works fine for about 6 month. This week I got the following display failure shown already twice, see this pictures of my problem today:

First I was able to see the top of the left half (blurry but visible):
[image]

A few seconds later the complete left half was corrupted:
[image]

I could still work with Windows, so this didn't freeze or something like that!
After switching off and on the monitor the problem was gone!
My operation system is Windows 8.1 x64!

What could be the reason for this failure?

- monitor defect
- notebook's graphics card defect
- windows software problem
- graphics card driver problem (Nvidia GTX 850m & Intel HD 4600)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: While the problem isn't reproducible / constant it's very difficult to say anything. Can you try another computer / monitor? That would help guessing better. In addition to your list it can be also your cable (/ adapter if you use one), we had a lot of problems with HDMI cables recently, replacing them every few months.

Comment: Check with some other laptop, so that you can find the problem is with your graphics card or not.